# Triangulate multiple faces with only two triangles

Tags: mesh, faces

I need to fill in all the empty squares in the top image, then I need to triangulate them as shown in (B). However, if I use the "triangulate faces" tool, I get (A).
(For your information, I used the knife tool to get (B) but I can't do that for all the squares...)
Thanks.
[image]

---

a new problem has arisen. If I use the technique proposed by FFeller (use Knife for a structure and multiply with Array), I get the following mesh when exported in stl...
[image]

Comment: Why don't you create the base geometry first, than use the Array modifier for a repeating pattern?

Comment: That's a good idea indeed. Thanks

Comment: Maybe applying the array before exporting would help?

Comment: Stl contains only triangles. The large "triangles" on the mesh not really triangles because they have 9 edges and 9 verts. Those have 6 180° angles but they still 9gons. What you can do is select the 9gon and press Y, this will separate it from the mesh, then select the 180° verts then press X>>Dissolve verts.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much FFeller !